# Finding an alternative for taking full backup daily

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL server and storing lot of data daily. I'm taking full backup daily which takes more than 5 hours to complete. Is there any idea to complete my backup process within a hour ? An alternative things to do?

Comment: what about taking a full backup weekly, and differential backup daily ?

Comment: Is there read only data in your database or every table is changing continuosly?

Comment: Do you have a way to keep track of the data that has changed? If so, why not only back up data that has changed from one back up to the next rather than backing up everything?

Comment: ahmed- Actually i'm planing having the same idea to implement. Still i need to ensure disadvantages taking a single full backup daily.

Comment: sepupic - yes i'm handling the continuously changing data

Comment: Gareth - i'm planning automate the backup process. Everyday checking and backing up the changing data is little hard.

Answer (score 1):

Daily differential backup (only changes will be backed up) and CloudBerry software will make you deal:)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely consider taking [differential backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-differential-database-backup-sql-server).  Depending on how much data is changing you may be able to take differential backups every hour or so, giving you a quick way to restore the hourly backup if needed. Perhaps complete a full backup once a week or every few days.

There are several considerations and I suggest you research it well to see if it will meet your specific needs, for example ([source](http://sqlmag.com/database-backup-and-recovery/step-step-approach-differential-backup-and-recovery)):

- If your databases are small or compress effectively enough so that your full and transaction log backups fall within storage and SLA limits, differential backups are unnecessary.
- If your databases change a lot between backups, you might as well perform full backups.
- If the changes to your database are few and the transaction log backups would take longer to restore than the differential backups, using differential backups might make sense and are worth investigating.

Other things to consider:

- Are you currently taking transaction log backups?  Should you be? What recovery model are you using?
- If you decide to do differential backups, be aware of things such as the "Copy only backup" option in SQL Server Management Studio.  These have implications for restoring data in a disaster recovery situation.
- In essence, you should educate yourself on SQL Server backup and restore **before** you make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the situation and to speed the backup you may consider differential and transaction log backups. You can do it through the studio, but to schedule it you will have to refer to a 3-rd party tool like CloudBerry.

Answer (score 0):

The alternate to taking full backups daily is taking incremental/ progressive incremental or reverse incremental backups.
An incremental backup copies the changes only from the last successful backups.
Progressive incremental has only on one full backup copy for the servers and takes incremental backups for the rest of cycle.

Reverse incremental supported by Veeam and DPM has its own mechanism to backup and store only incremental copies from the server, and store each copy as a full copy which allows quick restoration in case of disasters.

To configure this kind of backups, you can go for any enterprise level backup tool, but if you focus on cost effectiveness I would recommend Cloudberry backup.
I tried CloudBerry Cross-Platform Cloud Backup which provides a simple GUI to manage backup and restores and cloud storage account comes bundled with the software.You can also use the cloudberry explorer to view, move and manage your data on the cloud storage account.
It also provides enterprise backup features like job scheduling, CLI, compression and encryption.